# Group problems by description in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have certain type of warnings that repeat multiple times in my code. There is nothing I can do about them but ignore them.

I don't want to use SupressWarning because there are other warnings of the same type that I don't want to ignore.

If I could group the problems by description, then It would be easier for me to discriminate between warnings I can't do anything about, and warnings that I should care.

I was thinking of writing a plugin for Eclipse, but I don't want to commit so much time into it.

Any ideas? I googled for some time, but I could not find a solution.

[image]

Comment: You can add @SuppressWarnings to just the single 'new String' statement so that it does not suppress anything else.

Comment: Thanks. But I really don't want to change the code. Besides adding ~300 times that statement can pollute the code considerably.